# How do you parse large SQL scripts into batches?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, t-sql, parsing

I have a very large sql file I want to break up into batches for execution.
I want to make sure I'm parsing it the same way that SSMS and SQLCMD do.

Microsoft has a great mixed mode assembly named Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser with a class named Parser that seams like it would do the trick.

It wants an implementation of IBatchSource as an argument to SetBatchSource before calling Parse().

Where can I find an implementation of IBatchSource, and more information on how to make use of this functionality?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the assembly Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser in the GAC along with it's friend Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParserClient that contains implementations the interface IBatchSource.

```
namespace Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common
{
  internal class BatchSourceFile : IBatchSource
  internal class BatchSourceString : IBatchSource
}
```

The following conversation then occurred.

> *Assembly:* Hello! My name is
>   **Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ExecuteBatch**. Would you like to StringCollection GetStatements(string sqlCommand)?
>
> *Me:* Yes, I would, BatchParserClient assembly. Thanks for asking!

**Repeatable Instructions** (Do try this at home!)

- Install [Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Shared Management Objects](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16978)
- Copy Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser.dll and Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParserClient.dll from the GAC to a folder in your solution.
- Reference Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser & Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParserClient

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;

namespace ScriptParser
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         ExecuteBatch batcher = new ExecuteBatch();
         string text = File.ReadAllText(@"Path_To_My_Long_Sql_File.sql");
         StringCollection statements = batcher.GetStatements(text);
         foreach (string statement in statements)
         {
            Console.WriteLine(statement);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**App.Config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
   <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
   </startup>
</configuration>
```

Another option is to use the ScriptDom as described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32529415/26877.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom;

namespace ScriptDomDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TSql120Parser parser = new TSql120Parser(false);
            IList<ParseError> errors;
            using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(@"create table t1 (c1 int primary key)
GO
create table t2 (c1 int primary key)"))
            {
                TSqlFragment fragment = parser.Parse(sr, out errors);
                IEnumerable<string> batches = GetBatches(fragment);
                foreach (var batch in batches)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(batch);
                }
            }
        }

        private static IEnumerable<string> GetBatches(TSqlFragment fragment)
        {
            Sql120ScriptGenerator sg = new Sql120ScriptGenerator();
            TSqlScript script = fragment as TSqlScript;
            if (script != null)
            {
                foreach (var batch in script.Batches)
                {
                    yield return ScriptFragment(sg, batch);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // TSqlFragment is a TSqlBatch or a TSqlStatement
                yield return ScriptFragment(sg, fragment);
            }
        }

        private static string ScriptFragment(SqlScriptGenerator sg, TSqlFragment fragment)
        {
            string resultString;
            sg.GenerateScript(fragment, out resultString);
            return resultString;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but `File.ReadAllText` will still read the whole file into memory first. So with big files (maybe unreasonably big, but still), you have issues. Basically, a "streaming" interface would be required. As I have noted [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12154400/21567), `SQLCMD.EXE` is able to do that, and presumably also uses `IBatchSource`, albeit the native implementation and not the "managed" wrapper. The question remains: how to split the input text into chunks so that the BatchParser can understand it. (+1 though still, for a good contribution)

Comment: @Christian.K found answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32529415/26877 that might be an option for parsing your batches using the ScriptDOM.